# Why doesn't ALAssetLibrary -enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock: "stop" when I tell it to?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, block, alassetslibrary

I noticed that even though I set the `*stop` `BOOL` pointer to `YES`, my enumeration block is being executed twice. I thought setting `*stop = YES` would stop after the first one?

```
[lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Enumerating a group");

    //should stop after first?
    *stop = YES; 
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
}];
```

The logs:

```
2014-03-05 12:27:29:363 AppName[3625:1547] Enumerating a group
2014-03-05 12:27:29:379 AppName[3625:1547] Enumerating a group
```

From the documentation, `-enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:` is asynchronous, but is it also automatically parallelized? Both enumerations happen on the main thread, so maybe I should enforce my own stop? Seems weird to offer `stop` if it's not exactly enforced in the way the documentation suggests.

**EDIT**

For what it's worth, I added my own enforcement and it works. But why do I need to do this?

```
    __block BOOL stopItForReal = NO;
    [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Enumerating a group");

        //does not stop enumeration
        *stop = YES;

        //actually stops enumeration. I win, runtime!
        if (stopItForReal)
            return;
        stopItForReal = YES;

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
```

Comment: Apple documentation on ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock: `stop`
**A pointer to a boolean value; set the value to YES to stop enumeration.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When group enumeration is terminated, `ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock` is invoked with `group = nil`. So you can write something like:

```
if (group != nil) 
{
    // your code.
}
```

Comment: Yep, that totally works. Thank you! What a weird behavior. I imagine there must be pragmatic and/or legacy reasons why Apple chose to do this. I'll Accept your answer once the 5 min wait period is up.

Comment: Actually, that functionality can be used instead of completion block, like:
if (group) { [self.array addObject:group]; } else { [self.tableView reloadData]; }